# Proof of $BGl(n)\simeq Gr(n,\infty)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> What is a direct proof for the existence of a weak homotopy equivalence
>   between the Grassmanian $Gr(n):=Gr(n,\infty)$ and the classifying space
>   $BGL(n)$ of $GL(n)$?

They both represent the functor of isomorphism classes of rank $n$ vector bundles on some CW complex but perhaps there is a more direct proof to see this fact.

Comment: What is your definition of $BGL(n)$?

Comment: The bar construction, i.e. the realization of the simplicial space $...GL(n)\rightrightarrows *$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be the following:

The bar construction gives you a principal $GL_n$ bundle
$$GL_n\rightarrow EGL_n\rightarrow BGL(n)$$ with $EGL_n$ being weakly contractible.

For the Grassmannian one has a similar principal bundle 
$$GL_n\rightarrow V_n(\infty)\rightarrow G_n(\infty),$$ where $V_n(\infty)$ is the Stiefel manifold of $n$-frames and the map $V_n(\infty)\rightarrow Gr_n(\infty)$ is given by taking the span. The classifying map of this bundle gives you a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
GL_n @>{}>> V_n(\infty)@>{}>>G_n(\infty);\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
GL(n) @>{}>> EGL(n)@>{}>>BGL_n;
\end{CD}$$ of fiber bundles. The ladder of long exact sequences in homotopy groups then yields the result as $V_n(\infty)$ is weakly contractible.

Sidenote: Maybe it would be cleaner to do this first unstably for the bundle involving $V_n(k)$ and $Gr_n(k)$ to get a highly connected map $Gr_n(k)\rightarrow BGL_n$ and then passing to the colimit.

However, this is not a real answer to your question since I used that $BGL_n$ classifies principal $GL_n$-bundles. All I have proven is that if you have a principal bundle with a weakly contractible total space and you know that there is a classifying bundle, then the base space of the bundle one has started with is weakly equivalent to the base space of the classifying bundle.